# Should Active Storage binary variant files get pushed to version control?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I've been playing around with my web app in development and uploading images to the app, and when I push to bitbucket it includes all of the (many) binary files in the storage folder. I haven't changed the default Active Storage configuration. Should this be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The default `.gitignore` file for new Rails apps includes `/storage/*`:

```
# Ignore uploaded files in development
/storage/*
```

If you’re using Git, ensure your `.gitignore` file contains the above. Otherwise, configure your VCS to ignore `/storage/*`.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded my app from Rails 5.1.4 to Rails 5.2 and the .gitignore file didn't include that line by default.

Comment: @spitz it's not present because  you are upgrading. If you creating application directly in Rails 5.2, it will be there.